# Find a function $f$ that is continuous and bounded on $[0, \infty)$ but which is not uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

From Spivak Calculus 4th edition.

**Question:**
Find a function $f$ that is continuous and bounded on $[0, \infty)$ but which is not uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

I understand that functions that are not uniformly continuous inevitably have a slope that gets steeper and steeper.

However, given that $\sin(\frac1x)$ is not continuous at $0$, I am having trouble coming up with a function that satisfies this. All the variations on $\sin(x)$ I can come up with are all not bounded.

Comment: $\sin(1/x)$ oscillates more rapidly as $x \to 0$. You can come up with a similar function that oscillates more rapidly as $x \to \infty$ instead.

Comment: @angryavian OP knows that. It's not trivial to construct such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $\sin(x^2)$? This is bounded and has similar rapid oscillation as $x$ approaches $\infty$.

Comment: Why didn't I think of this :(

Comment: +1 for the simplicity

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$\sin(\big\lfloor\frac x\pi\big\rfloor\cdot x)$$It's pretty easy to show that this function is continuous, and the oscillation gets faster as the function approaches infinity.